# How to construct a second independent equation

Tags: systems-of-equations

Consider the following equation: $$Eq. 1\qquad f(t) = a(t) \sin(\omega t) + r(t)$$ where function $f(t)$ is known and functions $a(t)$ and $r(t)$ are unknowns. It is aimed to find these two unknown functions. Differentiating both side of above equation would result in following: $$Eq. 2\qquad f'(t) = a'(t)\sin(\omega t) + wa(t)\cos(\omega t) + r'(t)$$
Is it possible to consider $Eq. 2$ as an independent equation and consider both equations as a system to solve for unknown functions, either analytically or numerically?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: To solve what for what ? What is known and what is unknown ?

Comment: As I stated the f(t) is known and a(t) and r(t) are unknowns.

Comment: What do you want to solve, Have you other conditions on $a$ and $r$ like periodicity ?

Comment: Function a(t) is always positive. Function r(t) possesses negative, zero and positive values same as function f(t). These are all we know.